# accents missing and inputenc package ignored when changing from pdfLatex to XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, input-encodings

This is the error code that I get when changing from pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines
```

This is my preamble (it was from a template, originally designed to run with pdfLaTeX, but I decided to switch to XeLaTeX because of bibliography or some other function that was easier to implement with the other compiler):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs} 
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[]{placeins,flafter}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} \sloppy
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

¿Any clue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Neither `inputenc` not `fontenc` should be used with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: With \usepackage{fontspec} I solved the problem but I don't know if it's adequate

Comment: You are getting a warning, not an error. And it only tells you that the package did the right thing with xelatex: it does nothing.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik depends on the age of the texsystem. If OT1 is still the default encoding you would need fontspec to switch.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ooh, I didn't know that. I'll delete my comment :-)

Comment: The title mentions “missing accents”, but the example has no text.